# Why does Stripe return parameter_missing - success_url?

Tags: dart, post, stripe-payments, flutterflow

I make a post call to Stripe checkout.I pass multiple line_items because it is from a cart. But eveytime a trigger the call, Stripe return missing success url, even though i pass it. And when i look at the logs in Dashboard of Stripe, i see that the request body is just empty. But the body has data in DevTools. So i really don't know what i do wrong. I think the problem is not a missing success url, but more about the alyout of the list i think?

[Here is the payload in DevTools:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZKGI.png)

I have a list with data type winkelmandItemTypeSlijterij. What the code does is format that list in a list that Stripe expects.

This is the code:

I tried to format the list into the format Stripe expects, but without success

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/actions/actions.dart' as action_blocks;
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<String> nogEenStripe(
    List<WinkelmandItemTypeSlijterijStruct> winkelmandList) async {
  // Add your function code here!

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> aangepasteLijst = [];

  for (var item in winkelmandList) {
    aangepasteLijst.add({
      'price_data': {
        'price_data': {
          'product': 'prod_${item.product}'
        } // Formatteer productnaam
      },
      'quantity': item.aantal,
    });
  }

  // Maak de formuliergegevens aan
  Map<String, dynamic> formData = {
    'mode': 'payment',
    'line_items': aangepasteLijst,
    'success_url': "https://example.com/success",
    'cancel_url': "https://example.com/cancel",
  };

  // Voer de HTTP-postaanvraag uit naar de Stripe Checkout API
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions'),
    headers: {
      'Authorization':
         'Bearer xxxxxxx',
      'Content-Type':
          'application/json', // Content-Type gewijzigd naar 'application/json'
    },
    body: jsonEncode(
        formData), // Formuliergegevens worden nu als JSON-gecodeerd verzonden
  );

  // Controleer of de aanvraag succesvol was
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Retourneer de sessie-ID uit de Stripe Checkout API-response
    return jsonDecode(response.body)['id'];
  } else {
    // Retourneer een foutmelding als er een probleem was met de aanvraag
    throw Exception('Failed to create checkout session');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The product in your request was not a Stripe Product. The product ID (prod_xxx) should be created from Stripe [Products API](https://docs.stripe.com/api/products/create).

In addition, `unit_amount` was spelled incorrectly in the request. Your code showed `unit_amout`, `n` was missing in the `amount`.

I'd recommend checking your request against the Checkout Session integration doc to ensure that you set the correct request parameters and their values: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=stripe-hosted

You can also find the request logs in the Dashboard https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs to check the errors and requests that have been sent by your system.